# DjangoRestFramework: Nested relationships usage & Kanban REST structure

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

For my current project I'm using [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) and [Django Rest Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/).

I'm using [Nested Relationships](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) for all my views to get strictly what is needed to be displayed in them.
However I'm starting to wonder if it is a good practice or not.
Let's say I have a kanban view for a project application:

- I'd have a project
- With columns in it (stages)
- With tickets (tasks) in stages.

This would lead to a 3 layer serialization (project with its stages with their tasks). And even more layers if the tasks have tags to show on them in the kanban view, assigned_user with avatar and assigned tasks number ...
I have the following questions :

- While it does work perfectly for a few tasks, how will it scale for a project with 10.000 and even more tasks ? Since it would load let's say : 1 project, 5 stages, 10K+ tasks ?
- Is a pagination possible with such nested relations ?
- If using such nested relations is not the good way. When is it okay to use them ?
- If using such nested relations is not the good way for a kanban view, how should I do it ? Should I query (from the frontend) first the project, then query its stages with a .../project/stages endpoint , query somehow the tasks column by column and then reconstruct the whole structure in the frontend ?

If details are missing, feel free to say so and I'll provide more info.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: loading 10k+ things **at a time** anywhere is a drawback.  experts can say better.

Comment: @RanuVijay that's why for such a view (kanban) which would potentially holds thousands of tasks,... I think it's not usable. Then what would be the proper way to do it with REST endpoints ? However for endpoints which returns trivial things like users,... in lists I guess it doesn't matter.

Comment: what I meant is, the system can manage 10k+ nested records but fetching all at a go doesn't seem a good idea.  If possible you can go with 1 project, all its stages, and a few tasks per stage at starting and then load the remaining tasks.  Do you need all the tasks at first hand ?

Comment: there are ways to improve query perfirmances, which you can also try - select_related() "follows" foreign-key relationships, selecting additional related-object data when it executes its query.
prefetch_related() does a separate lookup for each relationship, and does the "joining" in Python. Also Caches so that your project query doesnt hit the database EVERYTIME.

Comment: @RanuVijay Yes so it coincides with what I suggest which is : first query the project, then query .../project/<id>/stages then for each stage query like 15 first tasks and provide a "load more" button to each stage. Otherwise for more standard views I guess it's okay to use nested relations directly. And, if for some reason I need more performance, instead of using such nested serializers I can make what you suggest with select_related and such. So it's more a "per-case" scenario than a standard implementation throughout all the application. Am I right ?